# Screencast 1024x768, What is the recommended encoding?

Tags: video-editor, encoding, mencoder, screencast

Using Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid, what is the recommended encoding for a screencast recorded at 1024x768?

The tools I used were RecordItNow (KDE package that works great on Gnome) and OpenShot Video Editor. I had to convert the OGV to AVI using mencoder in order to have it load in OpenShot successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use mpeg2video to record screencasts because it's less CPU intensive. Afterwards I convert to MPEG4 video (not x264) with FAAC audio works because I've found those codecs work well with all of the Linux video editors.

To make sure you have all of the codecs you need installed:
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53 libfaac0

You can use this command to convert videos to the editing format:
ffmpeg -i in.ogv -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec libfaac -sameq out.mp4